# Pass HTML value to JavaScript function called by multiple buttons

Tags: javascript

I have a function called by a bunch of buttons, and I would like to be able to tell which button has called the function. So that I can change the value of an input field based on which button was clicked.

```
<input id="input" type="text">
<button type="button" id="button00" onclick="name()" value="0">0</button>
<button type="button" id="button01" onclick="name()" value="1">1</button>

let input = document.getElementById("input");
function name() {
    input.value = input.value + buttonValue
}
```

Comment: do you want it like the current input value + the button clicked value??

Comment: Is the adding of the value to be an addition (sum) or a concatenation of strings? I note that you don't have a value set for the initial input.

Comment: it's a concatenation, it's the buttons value + the value already inside the input field, ex ( [31] ) click button "2". --> ([312])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send parameter when function is called. For example, I added button id when button is clicked.

```js
let input = document.getElementById("input");

var function_name = function(button_id) {
    input.value = input.value + button_id;
    console.log(button_id);
}
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text">
<button type="button" id="button00" onclick="function_name(this.id)" value="0">0</button>
<button type="button" id="button01" onclick="function_name(this.id)" value="1">1</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let input = document.getElementById("input");

function getNeme(value) {
    input.value = value
}
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text">
<button type="button" id="button00" onclick="getNeme(this.value)" value="0">0</button>
<button type="button" id="button01" onclick="getNeme(this.value)" value="1">1</button>
```